# How to show – not tell – nervousness?

Tags: phrase-requests

There’s a [saying in writing to “show; don’t tell”.](https://thewritepractice.com/show-dont-tell/) For example, instead of saying: “She was angry”, you would write: “Steam started coming out of her ears”, or: “Her fists slowly clenched up”. So it’s being more specific when showing emotions, actions etc. happening.

**I am looking for a “showing” phrase for being nervous.** The only one I could think of was: “Her heart was pounding heavily.” Thanks!

Comment: Imagine that you have to turn in this story to your teacher/editor in 15 minutes and you still haven't thought of the right words.  How do you feel?  How do you show it?

Comment: You might want to ask this on https://writing.stackexchange.com

Comment: You could replace "She was angry" with "Steam started coming out of her ears." However, that is a cliché, and you have to do better than that. "She was angry" may be better, providing that you can reflect her anger in something external to her. "Don't tell me the moon is shining -- show me the glint of light on broken glass." -- Anton Chekov

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to SE.writers (IMO)

Comment: I think the popularity of the idiom "show don't tell" arises as a paraphrase of the term "Show and Tell" - a practice used by teachers of very young children to encourage their self-confidence and descriptive use of conversation.

Comment: This would be better migrated to Writers SE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"butterflies in (one's) stomach"**

> - A feeling of nervousness.  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/butterflies+in+stomach)
> - to feel very nervous, usually about something you are going to do. [DC](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-butterflies-in-your-stomach)

Example sentences:

- Even experienced actors sometimes get butterflies before a performance.
- I used to get butterflies in my stomach before school tests.
- The butterflies in my stomach almost kept me from going on stage and performing.

Comment: But this isn't readily observable.

Comment: @HotLicks Neither is "her heart was pounding heavily" or "steam started coming out of her ears".

Comment: I think it's supposed to be "showed" as a sentiment. Like in comics if someone's getting angry, an illustrator would make that person's face red, and maybe steam coming out of her ears. So it's not really reality, but it's something that is usual to visualize.